# Create initialState on Store with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using repo from https://github.com/caspg/simple-data-table-map to implement into my existing app. However, in my existing app it contains various reducers with its own particular initialState. In the repo, the initialState is in the main.js

```
const initialState = {
    regionData: statesData,
    emptyRegions: [],
    sortState: { key: 'regionName', direction: 'ASC' }
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

I separate out the reducers in the repo ( without using the index.js to combine 3 of them ) so I can add them into my existing code.

```
const reducers = {
    User: require('../reducers/User.js'),
    Alert: require('../reducers/Alert.js'),
    Auth: require('../reducers/Auth.js'),
    Header: require('../reducers/Header.js'),
    PasswordPolicy: require('../reducers/PasswordPolicy.js'),
    AuditTrail: require('../reducers/AuditTrail.js'),
    StoragePolicy: require('../reducers/StoragePolicy.js'),
    DragAndDrop: require('../reducers/DragAndDrop.js'),
    UserProfile: require('../reducers/UserProfile.js'),
    emptyRegions: require('../reducers/map/emptyRegions.js'), //here is it
    regionData: require('../reducers/map/regionData.js'), //here is it
    sortState: require('../reducers/map/sortState.js'), //here is it
    Storage: require('./storage/Storage.js'),
    router: routerStateReducer
};
module.exports = combineReducers(reducers);
```

I have a file to combine all the reducers and each of their initialstate(which in the same file with the particular reducer)

stores/index.js

```
module.exports = function(initialState) {
const store = redux.createStore(reducers, initialState,

    compose(reduxReactRouter({ createHistory }), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
)

if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
        const nextReducer = require('../reducers')
        store.replaceReducer(nextReducer)
    })
}
return store
}
```

I tried to put the initiateState into sortState.js but it is not working.
The data do not show up. It must be something that from the author's repo

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

that set the initialState into the application state.

Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: 'I have a file to combine all the reducers and each of their initialstate' - could you provide the code where you combine the initialStates?

Comment: @cathalkilleen For example, I have one reducer file named User.js, 

   var initialState = {
    user_credential: {
        userId: null,
        username: null,
        isVerified: false,
        email: null
    }
};

module.exports = (state = initialState, action = '') => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'GET_USER':

...... so the initiateState is passed into module.exports = (state = initialState...) I tried in sortState.js but it is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `combineReducers(…)`, each Reducer needs to return its initial state on the first run.

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = { … }
const emptyRegionsReducer = (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    …
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Have look at [line 60](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L60) in the redux repo. For each reducer in the object:

```
const initialState = reducer(undefined, { type: ActionTypes.INIT })
```

what is triggered right away when `combineReducers()` is called.

Comment: In regionData.js, module.exports = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EDIT_ROW:
..., How can I assign state = initialState as it is an empty array.

Comment: But shouldn't it be ` module.exports = (state = statesData, action)` as assigned to the preloaded state above?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to initialize the state in Redux - the [docs explain the details very well](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html).

You can set the **global initialState** by passing it as an optional **second argument** to the `createStore` function, like this:

```
const initialState = { /*..initial state props..*/ }    
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

OR, you can set the initialState for an **individual reducer** in the following way (from official docs):

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT': return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT': return state - 1;
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Passing `state = 0` means that `state` is given the value 0 within that reducer when it is first initialized. After the `counter` reducer is initialized, the `state` value becomes whatever `counter` is in the Redux store. One important thing to note is that you must include the line `default: return state;` for this method to work.

In your case, it looks like you are using **both methods**. If you are happy with the initialState that you set within your reducers, then you should remove the `initialState` argument from `createStore`:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up setting the initiateState on individual reducer.

Comment: Yes, the docs do mention those two ways, but that works for simple values, what if your initial state is a dynamic API response like e.g. the first page of a list of resuls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777920/how-do-i-fetch-the-initial-redux-state-from-an-api-response?noredirect=1#comment109275845_61777920