# How do I fetch the initial Redux state from an API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Seen several questions about this but with many unclear and different answers.

I am rendering a list of items in the very first load of my component, and currently I'm triggering this fetch like so:

```
  fetchMovies = () => {
    console.log('component page:', this.props.movie.page);
    this.props.getMoviesIfNeeded(this.props.movie.page);
  };

  handleScroll = throttle(() => {
    let d = document.body;
    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    let windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    let height = d.offsetHeight - windowHeight;
    let scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / height);
    // if the scroll is more than 90% from the top, load more content.
    if (scrollPercentage > 0.90) {
      // this.fetchMovies();
      if (!this.props.movie.isFetching) {
        this.props.increasePage();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.movie.page === 1) {
      this.fetchMovies();
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
```

my problem with this is that naturally it is executed at every Route navigation to the component. (currently: list page => detail page => list page) and it is re-executed each time. 
I would like to remove this call to fetchMovies and move it to the initialState passed in:\

```
export default function configureStore() {
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  return createStore(
    reducers,
  + initialState, // there
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );
}
```

as described in the documentation: https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store#the-solution-configurestore . In this case, where should the HTTP Request live? Currently, the fetching is done in my actions file:

```
export let getMovies = (page = 1) => async dispatch => {
  let err, response;

  dispatch(requestMovies(page));
  [err, response] = await to(axios.get(`${apiUrls.base}/${apiUrls.theaters}`, {
    params: {
      page,
      api_key: '36081eca9a2ced64d616c59681881626',
    }
  }));
  console.log('request done with page:', page);
  if (err) return dispatch(throwError(err));
  debugger;
  return dispatch(receiveMovies(response.data));// somewhere here I want to trigger another action that increases the page...?
};
```

My application is not a SSR app (NextJS) but plain simple React.

*edit*
these are the other actions and reducers

```
// actions
function shouldFetchMovies(state, page) {
  if (!state.movie.movies.length) {
    return true;
  } else if (state.movie.isFetching) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return state.movie.movies;
  }
}

export function getMoviesIfNeeded(page) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchMovies(getState(), page)) {
      return dispatch(getMovies(page));
    }
  }
}

// reducers
const defaultState = {
  movies: [],
  total: 0,
  page: 1,
  isFetching: false,
};
export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREASED_PAGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        page: state.page + 1,
      };
    case 'REQUESTED_MOVIES':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case 'RECEIVED_MOVIES':
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: [...state.movies, ...action.response.results],
        // total: action.response.total_results,
        isFetching: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `dispatch(requestMovies(page));` sets the status of the data to be requested to loading=true and `dispatch(receiveMovies(response.data))` sets the status to false then why not add a `requested` property to how you store api results in the store. In your selector you select a result and if it's completely missing return an object where `requested` is false. In compnonentDidMount (or effect hook) check if requested is false before dispatching the action.

Comment: assumptions correct! I updated my question to show more of the code. I do have a `isFetching`, `Boolean` already. So you propose I add another Boolean that's toggled after the first fetch? Nice but it sounds like a workaround - isn't there a way to populate the state by doing an initial fetch when setting up the store and passing it in `defaultState` ?

Comment: There is a way to set inital state with the first page but you'll have to fetch data and render react-redux Provider only after the first page is fetched, used for initalState and store is created with that initial state. I thought you wanted to skip pages but see that you just keep fetching next page, if there are a lot of movies your app can break at some point (too many movies to be displayed). In your case you can recursively fetch movies until there are no more to be fetched`

Comment: The INCREASED_PAGE is run only when you reach the bottom of the page - its an infinite scroll :)

Comment: Your code should work fine if you change shouldFetchMovies: `if (!state.movie.movies.length && !state.movie.isFetching) { return true ...` then the did mount would not cause re fetching data

Comment: I have a 'detail' page - whenever you go to that page and back to the list, the fetch is triggered again . https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gkatsanos/anotherreactapp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

`initialState` - is a object. It's not the place you should call any fetch operations. The best place for side-effects is `componentDidMount` lifecylce method. So your implementation for callling is correct.

If you are going to change redux state you should use reducers. You have to create reducer for the action you use in `receiveMovies` action creator which will update app state. There you can get data from your response and update any state values you need.

Comment: see my updated code, I do use Reducers. Would the Reducers file be the place to do that initial fetch?

Comment: From the bolded part of the reducer docs in redux
**Given the same arguments, it should calculate the next state and return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation.**

Comment: initialState is defaultState in your code.

I see you have special action type called 'INCREASED_PAGE' and its reducer, you can call dispatch(<yourActionCreatorfor_INCREASED_PAGE>()) before
return dispatch(receiveMovies(response.data))

But I do not think it's a good idea.

Comment: You should check "shouldFetchMovies" condition in componentDidMount and call or not call getMovies action, not in actions creator. You have to connect redux state and dispatch to your component (if you did not).